# Is it possible to convert text into a single list in python?

Tags: python

```
text=policy institutional coherence enhance global macroeconomic stability including policy coordination policy coherence enhance policy coherence sustainable development respect country policy space leadership establish implement policies poverty eradication sustainable development multistakeholder partnerships enhance global partnership sustainable development complemented multistakeholder partnerships mobilize share knowledge expertise technology financial resources support achievement sustainable development goals countries particular developing countries encourage promote effective public publicprivate civil society partnerships building experience resourcing strategies partnerships data
```

Can we convert input like text mentioned above to an output like result?:

```
result= ['policy institutional coherence enhance global macroeconomic stability including policy coordination policy coherence enhance policy coherence sustainable development respect country policy space leadership establish implement policies poverty eradication sustainable development multistakeholder partnerships enhance global partnership sustainable development complemented multistakeholder partnerships mobilize share knowledge expertise technology financial resources support achievement sustainable development goals countries particular developing countries encourage promote effective public publicprivate civil society partnerships building experience resourcing strategies partnerships data']
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, just use

```
text = [text]
```

This will give you

> ['policy institutional coherence enhance global macroeconomic stability including policy coordination policy coherence enhance policy coherence sustainable development respect country policy space leadership establish implement policies poverty eradication sustainable development multistakeholder partnerships enhance global partnership sustainable development complemented multistakeholder partnerships mobilize share knowledge expertise technology financial resources support achievement sustainable development goals countries particular developing countries encourage promote effective public publicprivate civil society partnerships building experience resourcing strategies partnerships data']